# Encrypted HDD - enter passkey with on-screen keyboard and touch screen

Tags: encryption, touchscreen

I am building a personal media/documentation server with a (cheap) touch screen. I would like to have drive encryption, but without requiring a physical keyboard.

Being only moderately experienced with Linux/Ubuntu I feel that this should be possible as long as I load the drivers and software keyboard into the initrd/ramdrive. Unfortunately that is a bit beyond the scope of my knowledge.

I am willing to invest the time to get this working as a hobby project, but would like to ensure that my time would not be wasted.

**So my question for any gurus out there is:** Is it possible to load an on-screen keyboard with touchscreen support to enter the passkey for an encrypted drive?

edit:If it matters it is currently built as Ubuntu desktop using the alternate 12.04.4 installer.

Comment: This is still a problem with 20.04. I have a Surface Pro 3. I have to plug in a keyboard to enter the disk encryption password. After that point, no physical keyboard is needed. There is an on-screen keyboard available at the grub menu, but I cannot make one appear for the disk encryption password screen.

Answer (score 0):

A very nice on-screen keyboard ships with Ubuntu.  (If it is not included with the alternate installer, install it using  `sudo apt-get install onboard`).  The keyboard can be invoked by searching for and running `Onboard` from the Dash; it can be configured by launching `Onboard Settings` from the Dash.

The danger with an on-screen keyboard and touch (only) screen is that the user could potentially close the keyboard at the Lock-Screen or the Login-Screen, and would have no way to bring it back up.  (After having logged in, however, the user could easily tap on the Ubuntu Dash, and restart the keyboard, if necessary).

I wrote a script to address this and other issues with a touch-screen only keyboard system.  Perhaps it will be useful to you...

[Tablet Mode Switcher, Post # 259](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1911972&p=13023126#post13023126)

(When viewing the above post, if you log into ubuntuforums.org, you will be able to see the attached screenshots of the online keyboard).

Additionally, you can enable an onscreen keyboard from System Settings | Universal Access | Typing | On Screen Keyboard | On.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am aware of the on-screen keyboard, but from my understanding it would not (by default) be available for use while entering the encryption passkey because only a ramdrive is loaded at that point (due to the drive and OS being encrypted).